# How do I link each user to their data in Firebase for Swift 3?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a project integrated with Firebase. It has signup and login features. I have  personal information form to fill up for individual users. But when the users are different, all data are shown for all users. I need to show information related to linked users. The person should only be able to access his/her database. I couldn't find proper solution in Swift 3.

Comment: Where you faced the problem? It's too long code

Comment: I have written my problem in my question. There is no error in the project but  the database created by each users are accessed by all. The user's personal information should be accessed by him/her self and not by all users. The database should be linked to individual users. Did you get the question now?  @Saurabh Jain

Comment: Whoa - that's a lot of code to look through. Is there a reason you don't use the typical design pattern of storing user data in a /users node and then references to that users linked users within the same node? See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635341/how-to-retrieve-data-of-current-user-from-firebase/37635638#37635638). You could even do it the other way around and stored which users a user is linked to within their node - that would make querying a snap.

Comment: @Tamannah please see the Jay link

Comment: That's not my question. I need to link the user with only his/her database and not all the database about all user's information. Please, I am new to swift. Help me to sort out this problem. I have written all codes thinking somebody would ask to write all codes to know the full work. @ Saurabh Jain  @ Jay

Comment: I think you can see at View Controller file. I think the answer lies in there only cause database is created from there only. @  Jay

Comment: have you done this in Objective-C?

Comment: No, I have not done in Objective-C. Please help me out to solve it ??

Comment: @Tamannah: There is simply too much code in your question for anyone to efficiently be able to help. Please read how to create a [**minimal** complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is by far the best way to get help on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From best I can tell it seems you are not referencing the correct node in your database. You are seeing all of your users data because your variable `messageRef` is pointed at `/users`. If you'd like users to only see their data then you need to organize your data so that when you save a `messageItem` that is is at `/users/{user_id}`. Then properly access it by first getting the `user_id` and reading it from it's new location (`/users/{user_id}`).

so I'd change these lines from this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       messageRef = databaseRef.child("Users")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

to this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
       guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
       messageRef = databaseRef.child("Users/\(user.uid)")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: It shows error as : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<loginIntegration.User 0x600000152170> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key -KpxBRAArXyFC9EXGF0t.'
           But when i see on the database , the database is linked with its data. So the problem is with xcode now. Help me out to fix this ? @Doug

Comment: The problem is while fetching data on table view from firebase probably on Donate.

Comment: I solved it. I got hint from your answer so you deserve to get up vote and right answer. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks for passing on the good stackoverflow karma. You may also consider editing my answer to reflect where you did go wrong so that any in the future facing the same issue might find a more complete answer here. Cheers!